# Have Web API controller wait for IAsyncResult before completing?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a Web API controller. It calls a method that returns an IAsyncResult. When I call the controller, I get the error

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

How do I get the controller to wait for the asyncresult?

I was planning to use await, but I may just not have figured out the syntax for this use case.

I haven't found an existing answer on SO.

I'm using c# 4.5

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetGridDataAsync")]
public string GetGridDataAsync()
{
        var proxy = new Proxy();
        return proxy.BeginGetDataAsync("test", ar => proxy.EndGetDataAsync(ar));             
}

public IAsyncResult BeginGetDataAsync(string r, AsyncCallback callback){}

public DataResponse[] EndGetDataAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult){}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your method an async `Task<string>`, create a `Task` based on the `Async` methods in the `Proxy` class and `await` that

Example:

```
public async Task<string> GetGridDataAsync()
{
    var proxy = new Proxy();
    return await Task.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginGetDataAsync, proxy.EndGetDataAsync, "test", null);   
}
```

Comment: You should really use `Task.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginGetDataAsync, proxy.EndGetDataAsync, "test", null)` instead.

Comment: This still fails 90% of the time :(. Can you provide an example of how to consume GetGridDataAsync?