# How to wait for a Task<T> to complete in Web API controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to consume a method that returns an async task. The method is:

```
    public async Task<DataResponse[]> GetGridDataAsync(DataRequest[] requestCollection, object state)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.FromAsync<DataResponse[]>(BeginGetDataAsync(requestCollection, ar => EndGetDataAsync(ar), state), 
            EndGetDataAsync);
    }
```

When consuming it in a Web API controller, I get the following error 90% of the time:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

My attempt to consume it is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetGridDataAsync")]
    public IEnumerable<DataResponse> GetGridDataAsync()
    {
        var proxy = new Proxy();
        var task = proxy.GetGridDataAsync(dataRequest, new object());

        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();                
        }                        

        //var x = (IAsyncResult)task; //i also tried this
        //task.Start();
        //x.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        return task.Result;
    }
```

How can I block the thread until the request completes (or at least specify a timeout)? I'm going to consume this endpoint from Angular.

This is a follow up to my previous question: [Have Web API controller wait for IAsyncResult before completing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127183/have-web-api-controller-wait-for-iasyncresult-before-completing)

**Update 1:**
The exception is being thrown by return proxy.GetGridDataAsync(dataRequest, new object()). I can step through the BeginXXX function but my break point in EndXXX never gets hit. Not sure why.

On occasion I don't get the "asynchronous module or handler..." error above, and get a different error with stacktrace. But I'm not sure what it means:

```
{  
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Object cannot be null.",
"ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException",
"StackTrace":" at 
System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObjectNative(WaitHandle waitHandle, Object state, UInt32 timeOutInterval, Boolean executeOnlyOnce, RegisteredWaitHandle registeredWaitHandle, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean compressStack)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(WaitHandle waitObject, WaitOrTimerCallback callBack, Object state, UInt32 millisecondsTimeOutInterval, Boolean executeOnlyOnce, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean compressStack)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(WaitHandle waitObject, WaitOrTimerCallback callBack, Object state, Int32 millisecondsTimeOutInterval, Boolean executeOnlyOnce)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Func`2 endMethod)
at proxy.d__1.MoveNext() in proxy.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Hoppe: Are you absolutely sure no other asynchronous work is being done? If you are, please post a minimal repro.

Answer (score 4):

Change your controller to return a `Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>>` like this...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetGridDataAsync")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>> GetGridDataAsync()
{
    var proxy = new Proxy();
    return await proxy.GetGridDataAsync(dataRequest, new object());
}
```

Comment: Why await, why not just not mark the function `async` but keep the return type `Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>>` and return the task directly?

Comment: I agree with your changes, but i still get the error: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Answer (score 4):

When you call an `async` method, it is recommended to `await` it. In your method, you actually block until the task completes, which is exactly like running it synchronously.

If you want to return only when `GetGridDataAsync`  completes, you need to mark your method `async`, make it return a `Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>>` and `await` it:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetGridDataAsync")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>> GetGridDataAsync()
{
    var proxy = new Proxy();
    return await proxy.GetGridDataAsync(dataRequest, new object());
}
```

If you dont need to wait until `GetGridDataAsync` completes, you can save yourself the state machine generation and simply return the `Task`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetGridDataAsync")]
public Task<IEnumerable<DataResponse>> GetGridDataAsync()
{
    return proxy.GetGridDataAsync(dataRequest, new object());
}
```

Also, note that your `GetGridDataAsync` also creates a redundant state machine, as it does nothing with the awaited result. You can simply return the result without `await`, letting the caller `await` on it:

```
public async Task<DataResponse[]> GetGridDataAsync(DataRequest[] requestCollection, object state)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<DataResponse[]>(BeginGetDataAsync(requestCollection, ar => EndGetDataAsync(ar), state), 
        EndGetDataAsync);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to consume this from angular JS. Right now I'm just testing by hitting hte URL of the controller diretcly from the browser. So I can simply have angular wait on the result. However, I still get the error "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending" when implementing these changes. :(

Comment: First of all, if you use it from angular, make sure to use the `return await` of `GetGridDataAsync` version. Second, in which line is tge exception being thrown?

Comment: @Hoppe Do your `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` work properly without `FromAsync`? I think there might be an issue with that call